# image preview - change div to what has been clicked - Polymer (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have the following code for a "change your profile picture" type box.

Can anybody help me implement functionality whereby when I click on the smaller image boxes, the large image will change to the one currently selected?

I'm wanting to avoid JQuery if possible.

[**Please see my JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vfqqhfdy/)

```
<div class="vertical layout">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x320" class="pictureBox">
  <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
    <div class="buttons horizontal layout">
      <paper-button class="save" id="save">save</paper-button>
      <paper-button class="delete" id="delete">delete</paper-button>
      <paper-button class="cancel" id="cancel" dialog-dismiss>cancel</paper-button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="vertical-divider"></div>

  <div class="vertical layout">
    <div class="images"> 
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
    <div class="horizontal layout fileUploadContainer">
      <paper-button class="upload" id=uploadButton on-click="uploadButton">Upload</paper-button>
      <input type="text" readonly id="fileName" class="fileName" placeholder="File..." on-click="openUpload"></input>
      <input type="file" class="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" on-change="newFile">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, with onclick event on all small pictures which use clickImage function.

```js
function clickImage(image)
{
  document.getElementById("bigPicture").src = image.src;
}
```

```css
#bigPicture
{

  height:320px;
  width:320px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical layout">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x320" class="pictureBox" id="bigPicture">
  <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
    <div class="buttons horizontal layout">
      <paper-button class="save" id="save">save</paper-button>
      <paper-button class="delete" id="delete">delete</paper-button>
      <paper-button class="cancel" id="cancel" dialog-dismiss>cancel</paper-button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="vertical-divider"></div>

  <div class="vertical layout">
    <div class="images"> 
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="horizontal layout row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="image" onclick="clickImage(this)">
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="horizontal-divider"></div>
    <div class="horizontal layout fileUploadContainer">
      <paper-button class="upload" id=uploadButton on-click="uploadButton">Upload</paper-button>
      <input type="text" readonly id="fileName" class="fileName" placeholder="File..." on-click="openUpload"></input>
      <input type="file" class="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" on-change="newFile">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

enter image description here
```